# Lost activity when goes in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I have four activities in my application:
MainActivity
LoginActivity
ResetActivity 
ContentActivity

MainActivity starts LoginActivity automatically.

LoginActivity contains two buttons for :

Go ResetActivity / Go ContentActiviy.

if user select ResetActivity, this activity call itself three times (  recusrion ), just we increase "step" (int parameter).

Activities paths:

MainActivity ===> LoginActivity ===> ResetActivity( step 1) ===>  ResetActivity(step 2) ===> ResetActivity( Step 3).

My problem is when ResetActivity goes in background, my application starts from MainActivity, i want to keep the Activity with current step value.

I tried using in ResetPasswordActivity

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("currentStep", step);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        avedInstanceState.getInt("currentStep", step);
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to handle this issues ?

Comment: I think u should use sharedPreference , did you try it?